# Is there an available explanation of the difference between MimeKit and MimeKitLite?

Tags: mimekit

Love the MimeKit and MailKit libraries. Work great. Just discovered MimKitLite, but cannot find any info on that is "lite" about it. Is there an explanation somewhere? Thank you.

I checked in the release notes and on the MimeKit.net site and its doc. If it's there, I'm missing it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MimeKitLite contains a subset of the MimeKit API that does not include PGP, S/MIME or DKIM/ARC support. In other words, most of the MimeKit.Cryptography namespace has been ripped out in MimeKitLite.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Just found this in the "Building" section, so there is some doc on the main GitHub page for MimeKit


-    MimeKit.sln - includes projects for .NET 4.5/4.6/4.7/4.8, .NETStandard 1.3/1.6/2.0 as well as the unit tests.
-    MimeKitLite.sln - includes projects for the stripped-down versions of MimeKit that drop support for crypto.